# Как собрать точки с карты OSM? OSMnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap

Необходимо собрать сервисы(пекарни, парикмахерские, кафе и т.д.) с карты OSM, они же значки(точки) на карте.
Соответственно, чтобы собрать здания с карты используем:

```
tags = {'building': True}

# Получение списка зданий
    buildings_osm = ox.geometries_from_place('Volgograd, Russia', tags=tags)
```

А как же получить только точки? Полазил по документации и самой карте, не увидел у точек категории аналогичной *building* у зданий, чтобы их можно было собрать при помощи OSMnx.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:amenity

Answer (score 0):

Тут информация по точкам, их теги - https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:amenity

Как пример:

```
import osmnx as ox

tags = {'amenity': 'cafe'}
places = ox.geometries_from_place('Volgograd, Russia', tags=tags)

with open('places.txt', 'w') as f:
    for place in places.itertuples():
        f.write(f"{place.amenity}: {place.name} ({place.geometry})\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

для небольших объемов данных можно воспользоваться методом `geometries.geometries_from_point`:

```
import osmnx as ox

tags = {'amenity': ['restaurant', 'pub', 'cafe'],
        'building': 'hotel',
        'tourism': 'hotel'}
gdf = ox.geometries.geometries_from_point((48.700001, 44.516666), dist=500, tags=tags)
print(gdf[["name", "amenity", "addr:street", "addr:housenumber"]])
```

```
                                                                  name     amenity             addr:street addr:housenumber
element_type osmid                                                                                                          
node         1409435087                                           Швейк  restaurant                     NaN              NaN
             1645776089                                            Маяк  restaurant                     NaN              NaN
             3126225374                                       Блин Клуб        cafe                     NaN              NaN
             3273665314                                        ФрантЭль        cafe                     NaN              NaN
             3363115420                              Конфетки-бараночки        cafe         проспект Ленина                5
             6541857785                                      AngelCakes        cafe                     NaN              NaN
             6708189697                                        Якитория  restaurant                     NaN              NaN
             6828199924                                      Блин берри        cafe                     NaN              NaN
             7210803099   ИП Кичкин Андрей Андреевич (Кальян-бар)"Мята"        cafe                     NaN              NaN
             8808621730                                         Organza        cafe   набережная 62-й Армии                6
             9690501017                                            Река  restaurant   набережная 62-й Армии                6
             9792728168                                       Персонажи  restaurant   набережная 62-й Армии                6
             9916996040                                         Zicaffe        cafe         проспект Ленина               2А
             10092011153                                     Джаст кофе        cafe   улица Маршала Чуйкова                9
             10092011154                                         Jetlag        cafe   улица Маршала Чуйкова                9
             10810875206                                           Река  restaurant   набережная 62-й Армии                6
way          125910237                            Гостиница Облсовпрофа         NaN         Советская улица                5
             126054645                                          Мэритаж        cafe   набережная 62-й Армии                3
             678283838                                         ID Tower         NaN  Краснознаменская улица               5А
             844069348                                             Маяк  restaurant   набережная 62-й Армии               1А
```